# Ubuntu, установленная на флешку - ошибка read/64, error -110

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Устанавливал Ubuntu на флешку по следующим инструкциям:
[раз](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/ubuntu_%D0%BD%D0%B0_usb) и [два](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_ubuntu_%D0%BD%D0%B0_usb-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) (help.ubuntu.ru).

В uefi bios видна ubuntu, но при запуске возникает ошибка:

`usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110`
В похожих вопросах, отвечали, что она возникает при нехватке мощности, которая подается на usb. Но нормального решения я так и не нашел.

Используются:
ноутбук - DELL Inspiron 5558,
флешка - Silicon Power 16GB, USB 3.0, Ubuntu - 16.04.1 LTS

*Флешку пробовал втыкать во все usb порты.

Comment: Во-первых, проверьте соответствие архитектуры (32-64) вашего ноутбука и используемого образа ubuntu. Во-вторых, флешка должна быть отформатирована в fat32. В-третьих, попробуйте записать образ на другую флешку, на флешку меньшего размера (2 ГБ например), на отдельный раздел на флешке, etc.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, зачем форматировать ее в fat32. Я ведь создаю не LiveUSB, а устанавливаю полноценную ОС -> форматирую в ext4. Архитектуры соответствуют(64). Была попытка поделить флешку на два раздела (ext4 - 5 ГБ, fat32) - результат тот же. К сожалению, пока нет возможности попробовать другую флешку или подключить данную к другому ПК.

Comment: Похожая проблема на таком же ноуте, с той лишь разницей что у меня оно без кода (-110). Думается мне дело в матери.